# Server-side react with webpack 2 System.import

Tags: reactjs, webpack, isomorphic-javascript

I have an isomorphic app that's using webpack 2 to compile assets. I added chunking now with `System.import` which works on the webpack side but not on the server-side with function not found.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: are you using CSS modules? is it happening when you import your CSS into your component?

Comment: Yeah things can fall over when you use webpack dependant features on the server. I created a universal react boilerplate that uses webpack to bundle the server code too. That way you can share more between server and client code. [Check it here.](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally) May be a useful reference for you. I tried to comment the webpack stuff a lot.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few options available for getting `System.import` working with isomorphic/server-side rendering:

**Feature-detect `System` and polyfill**

Node allows you to call `require()` in a number of places and shimming `System.import` as follows should work:

```
if (typeof System === "undefined") {
  var System = {
    import: function(path) {
      return Promise.resolve(require(path));
    }
  };
}
```

If you're looking for a more robust implementation, there's also [es6-micro-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-micro-loader), which implements a `System` polyfill that works both in the browser and node.

**Use [babel-plugin-system-import-transformer](https://github.com/thgreasi/babel-plugin-system-import-transformer) to replace `System.import` with the equivalent UMD pattern**

i.e takes the following form:

```
System.import('./utils/serializer').then(function(module){
    console.log(module);
});
```

and transforms it down to:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var global = window;

    if (typeof global.define === 'function' && global.define.amd) {
        global.require(['utilsSerializer'], resolve, reject);
    } else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && (module.exports && typeof require !== 'undefined') ||
               typeof module !== 'undefined' && (module.component && (global.require && global.require.loader === 'component'))) {
        resolve(require('./utils/serializer'));
    } else {
        resolve(global['utilsSerializer']);
    }
}).then(function(module){
    console.log(module);
});
```

or

**[Build with Webpack targeting Node](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target)** (which will use require to load chunks):

```
webpack --target node
```

Comment: For those using webpack v2 and react I created a library to help with this. [`code-split-component`](https://github.com/ctrlplusb/code-split-component)

Answer (score 1):

One of these options might suit your needs:

1. Compile your code using Webpack w/ [target 'node'](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) and run the bundle server side.
2. If you're already compiling with babel using babel-register or similar you could try something like [babel-plugin-remove-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-remove-webpack) (might need a PR to get it to work with `System.import` in addition to `require.ensure`).
3. Define a global mock for `System.import` which just returns a resolved promise with the require()'d module.